# Source code required while debug project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My Eclipse with C project complains regarding missing source files while debugging:

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/string/../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S"

Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

How to solve this problem and provide required source code?

Comment: strlen() is a system provided function... so instead of stepping into that function when debugging, just set a breakpoint after the strlen() function and continue...

Comment: It is quite common that you don't have the sources of library functions. When single-stepping, execute them as a single line, don't step into them.